# Defining mobx-react-lite observer generics for props

Tags: typescript, mobx, mobx-react

Unable to define observer proptypes with mobx-react-lite.

I've tried using the generics for the observer function but it provides an error.

Doing something like this is fine:

```
import { observer } from 'mobx-react-lite';

type PassedProps = {
  foo: string,
  num: number
}
const Element = (props: PassedProps) => null;
observer<PassedProps>(Element)
```

But in a more complex example:

```
import { observer } from 'mobx-react-lite';

import { StoreContext } from 'index';

export function connect<MappedProps, PassedProps> (
  mapStoreToProps: (store: any, ownProps:PassedProps) => MappedProps,
  UIComponent: React.FunctionComponent<MappedProps & PassedProps>
) {
  const WrappedComponent = (props: PassedProps) => {
    const store = React.useContext(StoreContext);
    const mapped = mapStoreToProps(store, props);
    return UIComponent({...mapped, ...props});
  }
  return observer<PassedProps>(WrappedComponent);
}
```

It errors:

```
Type 'PassedProps' does not satisfy the constraint 'object'
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course I figure it out now. I had to define the generic types constraints:

```
export function connect<MappedProps extends object, PassedProps extends object> (
  mapStoreToProps: (store: any, ownProps:PassedProps) => MappedProps,
  UIComponent: React.FunctionComponent<MappedProps & PassedProps>
) {
  const WrappedComponent = (props: PassedProps) => {
    const store = React.useContext(StoreContext);
    const mapped = mapStoreToProps(store, props);
    return UIComponent({...mapped, ...props});
  }
  return observer<PassedProps>(WrappedComponent);
}
```